# Disable word wrap when open select2 drop down menu

Tags: jquery, width, jquery-select2

How i can disable word wrap when open select2 drop down menu?

[image: select2]

in next picture when i use standard GUI, words not moved to a new line and line width is increased

[image: standart windows GUI dropdown menu]

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the `width` option? https://select2.github.io/options.html#width

Comment: yes i tried, but i need resize position area (option tag), not width of select tag ...

Answer (score 11):

You can set `dropdownAutoWidth` as `true`:

```
$("selector").select2({
    dropdownAutoWidth : true
});
```

Hope this helps.